# R optimization solver optimx::optimx vs. optim function

Tags: r, machine-learning, optimization

It seems R `optimx::optimx` is better than `optim`, according to the document, it is "provides a replacement and extension" for `optim`. It even has gradient checking build in. After using it, I almost never use `optim`.

However, I recently tried one reasonable scale problem with ~10K parameters to optimize using conjugate gradient descent (CG). Both objective and gradient takes few seconds to evaluate.

Surprisingly, `optimx` does not work at all (no response in given time), but `optim` works well?

Could anyone tell me the reason? Is gradient checking backfire? What's the pros and cons for two solvers?

Comment: I think we'd need to see an example.  I will say that most of the optimizers that R provides are (in my experience at least) not well suited for extremely high-dimensional (10K parameters) optimization - usually these need more specialized tools.  Also, this seems to be more of a StackOverflow than a CrossValidated question.

Comment: @BenBolker thanks Ben, I think provide a reproducible example may not easy. A lot of code and data. If experienced user like you do not have any ideas by first glance, may be I should not ask this question.

Comment: Isn't this off-topic because it askes for programming help?

Comment: @StudentT yes, it is off topic and I voted to move to stackoverflow. thanks

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ might be a good location for this question,. But you should provide more details of what you ran, which algorithmic options (only Conjugate Gradient?), details of your problem, etc. Did you try the L-BFGS-B option?  If not, why not?

Comment: Many optimx algorithm choices apparently use the same back-end solver implementations as the optim counterparts, so should work the same.  Is this true for conjugate gradient and L-BFGS-B? I think this is not a "state of the art" conjugate gradient implementation.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone you are right, I tried both BFGS and CG, both of them does not work. But in matlab `fmincg` by Carl Edward Rasmussen, works well.